# Why you don't need to suffix a literal 1.0 with an f, when initializing a Float object using new keyword?

Tags: java

I'm currently preparing to take OCA exam, one of the topic discussed in the book am reading is to define primitive variables like `int`, `double`, `float` ... To declare and initialize a `float` variable you have to suffix the literal with an f, for example:

```
float a = 1.0f; // this compiles
float a = 1.0; // Doesn't compile
```

because otherwise the literal(1.0) will be considered to be a `double`. I have a question with the following line, why does it compile without an f suffix on it?

```
Float flt = new Float(1.0); // why this line compile without f suffix on 1.0?
```

Comment: i should have checked this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float(double) documentation before i ask the question!

Answer (score 2):

[A `double` is accepted as one of the parameters to the constructor of `Float`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float-double-)  If it weren't, it *definitely* wouldn't compile.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct,i should have checked the documentation before i ask the question! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float(double)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float(double)) constructor is overloaded to accept either a `float` or a `double` parameter.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct,i should have checked the documentation before i ask the question! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float(double)